# How to get index() of a select element?

Tags: jquery, html-select

**Desired Behaviour**

Get accurate index number of `<select>` element.

**Current Behaviour**

`0` is returned regardless of actual index number.

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/hsp6jeLh/

**HTML**

```
<div class="my_class">
    <select>
        <option value="none">don't click me</option>
        <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="my_class">
    <select>
        <option value="none">click me</option>
        <option value="bar2">bar2 - select me</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("change",".my_class select", function() {
console.log($(this).index());
console.log("Why isn't the above value 1?")
});
```

**Edit 01:**

Ergh, just realised I should probably add a class to the select element and pass that through to the `on()` method.  Will try now...

No, that didn't work either:  http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/hsp6jeLh/5/

Comment: @Cattla - Your suggestions seems to work, thank you.

Comment: Do you want the index of the `select` or the index of the selected `option`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User @Cattla's suggestion (which seems to be deleted) worked:

http://jsfiddle.net/hsp6jeLh/6/

```
$(document).on("change",".my_class", function() {
console.log($(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `index()` works only on adjacent elements. If you remove the closing and opening `div` in the middle it works like you expect it:

```
<div class="my_class">
    <select>
        <option value="none">don't click me</option>
        <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value="none">click me</option>
        <option value="bar2">bar2 - select me</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hsp6jeLh/8/

Comment: That's still the index of the select element.

Comment: Yes, it's the index of the `select` element. From what I understand, the OP wanted the index of the `select` not of the selected `option`